# Spring Integration : int-http:inbound-gateway with url Path Variables

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-integration

I am trying to test an Inbound http gatway using Spring Integration int-http:inbound-gateway:

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="correlateOutgoingMessage"
    supported-methods="POST" request-channel="toOutCorrelator"
    reply-channel="fromOutCorrelator" view-name="/correlateOutgoingMessage"
    path="/correlateOut/{origin}/{msgtype}/{priority}"
    reply-timeout="50000">
    <int-http:header name="origin" expression="#pathVariables.origin" />
    <int-http:header name="msgtype" expression="#pathVariables.msgtype" />
    <int-http:header name="priority" expression="#pathVariables.priority" />
</int-http:inbound-gateway>
```

My Web.xml :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>correlateOut</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/intg-schema.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>correlateOut</servlet-name>
    <!-- controler/* -->
    <url-pattern>/correlateOut/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Using the RestTemplate I am trying to make a POST request to the gateway:

The

```
uri =  "http://localhost:8080/test/correlateOutgoingMessage/{origin}/{msgtype}/{priority}"

    String origin = "xxxx";
    Integer msgtype = 2333;
    Integer priority = 2;

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);

    HttpEntity<?> request = null;

    ResponseEntity<String> httpResponse = null;

    request = new HttpEntity<Object>(messageContent);


    httpResponse = template.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, request,
            String.class, getUrlParams(origin, msgtype, priority));
```

I am alway getting NOT FOUND 404, would you any please give me some hints?

Thank you very much!

Comment: can you include in your post the uri you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should show the `uri` which you use to send HTTP request.

From other side if you map servlet to the `/correlateOut/*` you must not to use it in the target `mapping`, because all other endpoints are under that context.

So, your `path` should be `path="{origin}/{msgtype}/{priority}"`